CiviRule based on "Activity Date reached" - how to stop it triggering an email every 24 hours after that date
LINKED TRIGGER: Activity Date reached ; Activity with type XX AND Status XX
Action is to then send an email. So for someone with eg 3 July, we want an email sent on 3 July.
Excellent.
But it then wrongly imo keeps sending them out every 24 hours. ie one goes at 00:00:00 on the 4th and the 5th etc.
is this a bug? or is there something more to do to somehow limit it to only send once?

I do not think it is a bug as the condition is still met? The date is still reached? What I have done in the past is add the contact to a group as well and then add the condition 'is not in group' to avoid sending it again? Or add a specific activity and add a condition that that activity does not exist for the contact?

But I could also add a tick box "only send once" if there is funding?

Thanks Erik. i think it would be a good option to add. will raise with the Org. Yep otherwise i thought of the Group/Activity solution but it feels like add more data unnecessarily

Guess i think 'reached' means '=' and for you it means '>='
